# How to create a column with percentages for specific values for a group in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataset

```r
dat = structure(list(mdm = 7:8, price = c(100L, 200L), count = c(200L, 300L)),
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I need to transform this data by adding a column with percentages for each `mdm` group. Each group should have a `perc` column with values

```
50, 60, 70, 80, 85, 90, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 110, 115, 120, 130, 140, 150
```

where opposite the value `100`, there should be a `price` and `count` value for each group of `mdm` from the `dat` dataset.

Desired output:

```
perc    price   count
50  NA  NA
60  NA  NA
70  NA  NA
80  NA  NA
85  NA  NA
90  NA  NA
95  NA  NA
96  NA  NA
97  NA  NA
98  NA  NA
99  NA  NA
**100   100 200**
101 NA  NA
102 NA  NA
103 NA  NA
104 NA  NA
105 NA  NA
110 NA  NA
115 NA  NA
120 NA  NA
130 NA  NA
140 NA  NA
150 NA  NA
50  NA  NA
60  NA  NA
70  NA  NA
80  NA  NA
85  NA  NA
90  NA  NA
95  NA  NA
96  NA  NA
97  NA  NA
98  NA  NA
99  NA  NA
**100   200 300**
101 NA  NA
102 NA  NA
103 NA  NA
104 NA  NA
105 NA  NA
110 NA  NA
115 NA  NA
120 NA  NA
130 NA  NA
140 NA  NA
150 NA  NA
```

`mdm=7` values for price and count are equal to 100 and 200, so we put them down near the point where `100`.

`mdm=8` values for price and count are equal to 200 and 300, so we put them down near the point where `100`.

What is the easy way to do it? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge` it with an `expand.grid`.

```
merge(cbind(dat, perc=100), 
      expand.grid(mdm=unique(dat$mdm), perc=c(50, 60, 70, 80, 85, 90, 95, 96, 97,
                                              98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 
                                              110, 115, 120, 130, 140, 150)), 
      all=TRUE)
#    mdm perc price count
# 1    7   50    NA    NA
# 2    7   60    NA    NA
# 3    7   70    NA    NA
# 4    7   80    NA    NA
# 5    7   85    NA    NA
# 6    7   90    NA    NA
# 7    7   95    NA    NA
# 8    7   96    NA    NA
# 9    7   97    NA    NA
# 10   7   98    NA    NA
# 11   7   99    NA    NA
# 12   7  100   100   200
# 13   7  101    NA    NA
# 14   7  102    NA    NA
# 15   7  103    NA    NA
# 16   7  104    NA    NA
# 17   7  105    NA    NA
# 18   7  110    NA    NA
# 19   7  115    NA    NA
# 20   7  120    NA    NA
# 21   7  130    NA    NA
# 22   7  140    NA    NA
# 23   7  150    NA    NA
# 24   8   50    NA    NA
# 25   8   60    NA    NA
# 26   8   70    NA    NA
# 27   8   80    NA    NA
# 28   8   85    NA    NA
# 29   8   90    NA    NA
# 30   8   95    NA    NA
# 31   8   96    NA    NA
# 32   8   97    NA    NA
# 33   8   98    NA    NA
# 34   8   99    NA    NA
# 35   8  100   200   300
# 36   8  101    NA    NA
# 37   8  102    NA    NA
# 38   8  103    NA    NA
# 39   8  104    NA    NA
# 40   8  105    NA    NA
# 41   8  110    NA    NA
# 42   8  115    NA    NA
# 43   8  120    NA    NA
# 44   8  130    NA    NA
# 45   8  140    NA    NA
# 46   8  150    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is tidyverse approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

vector <-  paste(c(50, 60, 70, 80, 85, 90, 95:105, 110, 115, 120, 130, 140, 150), collapse = ", ")

dat %>% 
  group_by(mdm) %>% 
  mutate(perc = vector) %>% 
  separate_rows(perc, sep=",", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(perc, price, count) %>% 
  mutate(across(-perc, ~ifelse(perc==100, ., NA_real_))) %>% 
  print(n=50)
```

```
  perc price count
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    50    NA    NA
 2    60    NA    NA
 3    70    NA    NA
 4    80    NA    NA
 5    85    NA    NA
 6    90    NA    NA
 7    95    NA    NA
 8    96    NA    NA
 9    97    NA    NA
10    98    NA    NA
11    99    NA    NA
12   100   100   200
13   101    NA    NA
14   102    NA    NA
15   103    NA    NA
16   104    NA    NA
17   105    NA    NA
18   110    NA    NA
19   115    NA    NA
20   120    NA    NA
21   130    NA    NA
22   140    NA    NA
23   150    NA    NA
24    50    NA    NA
25    60    NA    NA
26    70    NA    NA
27    80    NA    NA
28    85    NA    NA
29    90    NA    NA
30    95    NA    NA
31    96    NA    NA
32    97    NA    NA
33    98    NA    NA
34    99    NA    NA
35   100   200   300
36   101    NA    NA
37   102    NA    NA
38   103    NA    NA
39   104    NA    NA
40   105    NA    NA
41   110    NA    NA
42   115    NA    NA
43   120    NA    NA
44   130    NA    NA
45   140    NA    NA
46   150    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `complete` from `tidyr`:

```r
tidyr::complete(
  cbind(dat, perc = 100),
  mdm, perc = c(50, 60, 70, 80, 85, 90, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 110, 115, 120, 130, 140, 150)
)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 46 × 4
     mdm  perc price count
   <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
 1     7    50    NA    NA
 2     7    60    NA    NA
 3     7    70    NA    NA
 4     7    80    NA    NA
 5     7    85    NA    NA
 6     7    90    NA    NA
 7     7    95    NA    NA
 8     7    96    NA    NA
 9     7    97    NA    NA
10     7    98    NA    NA
11     7    99    NA    NA
12     7   100   100   200
13     7   101    NA    NA
14     7   102    NA    NA
15     7   103    NA    NA
16     7   104    NA    NA
17     7   105    NA    NA
18     7   110    NA    NA
19     7   115    NA    NA
20     7   120    NA    NA
21     7   130    NA    NA
22     7   140    NA    NA
23     7   150    NA    NA
24     8    50    NA    NA
25     8    60    NA    NA
26     8    70    NA    NA
27     8    80    NA    NA
28     8    85    NA    NA
29     8    90    NA    NA
30     8    95    NA    NA
31     8    96    NA    NA
32     8    97    NA    NA
33     8    98    NA    NA
34     8    99    NA    NA
35     8   100   200   300
36     8   101    NA    NA
37     8   102    NA    NA
38     8   103    NA    NA
39     8   104    NA    NA
40     8   105    NA    NA
41     8   110    NA    NA
42     8   115    NA    NA
43     8   120    NA    NA
44     8   130    NA    NA
45     8   140    NA    NA
46     8   150    NA    NA
```